# Magento API limitations

Tags: php, .net, api, magento, xml-rpc

I'm currently working on an upload tool for a client using .Net to upload via the XML-RPC calls.  I am currently hitting two brick walls.

One is creating configurable products.  Have I missed some documentation, is this possible?

The other problem is adding data into drop down attributes for things like size.  Is this possible via the API?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend the Magento API, here is a [blog post](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/extending-the-magento-api/) as a starting point.  As a word of warning, I suspect you will find configurable products to be quite a challenge.  If you can manage it, I suspect you will find quite a bit of interest from users wanting to purchase the code... some incentive for you :)

Comment: Well, it's not a big challenge. Just some attributes linked together.

Answer (score 0):

As many people have opined in the past, the default API for adding products will not let you relate configurable products.

Comment: is there a good resource for changing the default API to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

No, not possible with the default api.

Altough you can write your own apis.

If you want to realise some magento stuff it is usually good to have a look at the admin controllers and replicate them into the APi.